# studentBindingSource.Add(new Student()); error SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have error when i try to add new user to my databse using this code:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objState = EntityState.Added;
        pic.Image = null;
        pContainer.Enabled = true;
        studentBindingSource.Add(new Student());
        studentBindingSource.MoveLast();
        txtFullName.Focus();
    }
```

It see out me a error error System.InvalidOperationException: "The objects added to the BindingSource list must be of the same type."

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Collection (such as List) can only contain one data type at a time.

For example, an array of Strings can only contain Strings. Adding an Integer to it will give you an issue

There isn't enough code for me to tell you exactly what's happening, but it seems your `studentBindingSource` collection is not meant to contain students. It contains another data type